# highcharts: pie chart - reduce number of slice

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart with so many slices that is very hard to read it. Is it possible to reduce the number of slices, by grouping the smallest in just one named "others", or hiding them?

Comment: Couldn't you just not pass so many items to Highcharts?  Since you control the JSON you send, you could aggregate them yourself before sending.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883606/group-smaller-slices-in-pie-charts-to-improve-readability

Comment: As OP, I would love to see this behaviour built it: you would specify the max number of slices to show, the name of the "others category" as well as the sort column and order. Then highchart could automatically aggregate all remaining columns into the others category, and a drill down with details when clicked. Also, when exporting, you would see all categories (no grouping there). Doing all that manually is a pain.

Answer (score 6):

No. This behaviour is not built into highcharts.

The easiest way to achieve this is by manually changing the data you pass to the chart. Ie if you do the grouping into a category 'Others' before you pass the data and render the chart

Answer (score 0):

Pasting some info in here as a pointer for people that would like to do the above with javascript outside of Highcharts, like i did myself.

```
for(i=0; i<dataJSON.finished.length; i++) {
    //console.info(i);
    if(dataJSON.finished[i].name !== '_all_' && dataJSON.finished[i].name !== 'Anders')         {
      tempValue=0;
      for(j=0; j<dataJSON.finished[i].data.length; j++) { tempValue += dataJSON.finished[i].data[j]; }
      if(tempValue / totalValue > 0.02) {
        pieData.push({ name:dataJSON.finished[i].name, y:tempValue });
      } else andersValue += tempValue;
    }
  }

  //console.info(pieData);
  pieData.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.y > b.y) ? -1 : ((b.y > a.y) ? 1 : 0);});
  pieData.push({ name: "Overig", y: andersValue });
```