# Group Smaller Slices in Pie Charts to Improve Readability

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I want to group data thar have under 10% percentage to be grouped to slice of pie named others. Is it possible?
[Pie-chart](http://jsfiddle.net/9bu0u8zx/)

```
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2]
            ]
        }]
```

Comment: How about checking your data and restructuring it with this in mind before creating the chart?

Comment: Isnt't there an automated way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to calculate slightly different data. Iterate over the entries looking for items with < 10%. Add these to an 'other' category.

Something like this:

```
 var data = [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2]
        ];
var newData=[];
var other=0.0;
for (var slice in data) {

    if (data[slice][1] < 10) {
        other += data[slice][1];
    } else {
        newData.push(data[slice]);
    }
}
newData.push(['other',other]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q25u2hyr/